# ternary operator check return 0 while checking jsx react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
    {!this.state.isOpen ? 
            (<Link to="" onClick={() => this.handleClick('j')}>Take a bow</Link> | 
            <Link to="" onClick={() => this.handleClick('r')}>Down</Link>  )
            : '' }
```

Why Link to shows me 0 when using multiple line if I use one  component does work for me can you please elaborate me how this is working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need a [`React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) or its short syntaxt `<></>`.

```
{
    !this.state.isOpen ?
    <>
        <Link to="" onClick={() => this.handleClick('j')}>Take a bow</Link>
        |
        <Link to="" onClick={() => this.handleClick('r')}>Down</Link>
    </>
    :
    null
}
```